# Make Show/Hide form auto scroll

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make it so that when a the next row, or question 2, 3, 4, and so on, auto scrolls to that row or question so the user does not have to manually scroll to view the next question because it can become a hassle and it decreases the amount of time answering the questions. I've tried to add the auto scroll to the div but the images disappear.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style type='text/css'>
    .radio div[type='radio'] {
        background: url($image) no-repeat #eee;
        height:55px;
        width:60px;
        border:1px solid #DDD;
        border-radius:10px;
        padding:1px;
        float:left;
        margin-right:10px;
        cursor:pointer
    }
    .radio div.active{
        box-shadow:0 0 2px 1px #00f inset;
    }
    .tablebuttons img {
        width: 60px;
        height: 55px;
        border: 0px solid #666;
        background: #fff;
        display:block;
        border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    }
    .question {
        margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
        display: none;
        clear: both;
    }
    #linkDiv {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .clear {
        clear: both;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).load(function(){
$('.radio div').on('click', function() {
var $this   = $(this),
$parent = $this.parent(),
value   = $this.attr('value');

$parent.children().removeClass('active');
$this.addClass('active');
$parent.attr('value', value);

//get all selected radios
var q1=$('div[name="q1"].active');
var q2=$('div[name="q2"].active');
var q3=$('div[name="q3"].active');
var q4=$('div[name="q4"].active');

//make sure the user has selected all 3
if (q1.length !== 0 && q2.length !== 0 && q3.length !== 0 && q4.length !== 0)
{
    //now we know we have 3 radios, so get their values
    q1=q1.attr('value');
    q2=q2.attr('value');
    q3=q3.attr('value');
    q4=q4.attr('value');

    // activate button
    $('#next_button').removeAttr('disabled');

    //now check the values to display a different link for the desired  configuration
    if (q1=="AT&T" && q2=="8GB" && q3=="Black" && q4=="Black")
    {
        $('#next_button').val('att 8gb black').click(function() {  
window.location.href='http://google.com/' } );
    }
    else if (q1=="AT&T" && q2=="16GB" && q3=="White" && q4=="Black")
    {
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button value=Next   
onclick=\"window.location.href='http://bing.com/';\">another option</input>";
    }
    else if (q1=="AT&T" && q2=="16GB" && q3=="Black" && q4=="Black")
    {
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button value=Next 
onclick=\"window.location.href='http://gmail.com/';\">oops</input>";
    }
    else if (q1=="AT&T" && q2=="8GB" && q3=="White" && q4=="Black")
    {
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button value=Next 
onclick=\"window.location.href='http://hotmail.com/';\">can't</input>";
    }

    else if (q1=="Unlocked" && q2=="8GB" && q3=="White" && q4=="Black")
    {
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button value=Next 
onclick=\"window.location.href='http://wepriceit.webs.com/';\">red</input>";
    }
    else if (q1=="Unlocked" && q2=="8GB" && q3=="Black" && q4=="Black")
    {
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button value=Next 
onclick=\"window.location.href='http://webs.com/';\">orange</input>";
    }
    else if (q1=="Unlocked" && q2=="16GB" && q3=="White" && q4=="Black")
    {
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button value=Next 
onclick=\"window.location.href='http://gazelle.com/';\">green</input>";
    }
    else if (q1=="Unlocked" && q2=="16GB" && q3=="Black" && q4=="Black")
    {
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button value=Next 
onclick=\"window.location.href='http://glyde.com/';\">blue</input>";
    }
}

}); 

var questions = $(".question");
var showQuestions = function(index) {
console.log("showQuestions index=" + index);
for(var i=0; i<questions.length; i++) {
    if(i < index) {
        questions.eq(i).css("display", "block");
    } else {
        questions.eq(i).css("display", "none");
    }
}    
}

for(var i=0; i<questions.length; i++) {
(function(index) {
    questions.eq(index).find("div[type='radio']").on("click", function() {
        showQuestions(index+2);
    })
})(i);
}
showQuestions(1);

});//]]>  

</script>

</head>
<body class="questionnaire">

<form name="quiz" id='quiz'>

<div class="question">
    <h4>Choose your series.</h4>
    <div class="radio" id="form">
        <div class="tablebuttons" type="radio" name="q4" value="iPhone-3GS">
            <img width="50px" height="50px"  
src="http://wepriceit.webs.com/Images/iPhone-3GS.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="tablebuttons" type="radio" name="q4" value="iPhone-4">
            <img width="50px" height="50px" 
src="http://wepriceit.webs.com/Images/iPhone-4.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="tablebuttons" type="radio" name="q4" value="iPhone-4S">
            <img width="50px" height="50px" 
src="http://wepriceit.webs.com/Images/iPhone-4S.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="tablebuttons" type="radio" name="q4" value="iPhone-5">
            <img width="50px" height="50px" 
src="http://wepriceit.webs.com/Images/iPhone-5.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="tablebuttons" type="radio" name="q4" value="iPhone-5">
            <img width="50px" height="50px" 
src="http://wepriceit.webs.com/Images/iPhone-5.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="tablebuttons" type="radio" name="q4" value="iPhone-5">
            <img width="50px" height="50px" 
src="http://wepriceit.webs.com/Images/iPhone-5.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br class="clear" />
<div class="question">
    <h4>What carrier do you have?</h4>
    <div class="radio" id="form">
        <div class="tablebuttons" type="radio" name="q1" value="AT&T">
            <img width="50px" height="50px" src="http://wepriceit.webs.com/Images/ATT- 
logo.png" />
        </div>   
        <div class="tablebuttons" type="radio" name="q1" value="Unlocked">
            <img width="50px" height="50px"   
src="http://wepriceit.webs.com/Images/Factory-Unlocked.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br class="clear" />
<div class="question">
    <h4>What is your phones capicity?</h4>
    <div class="radio" id="form">
        <div class="tablebuttons" type="radio" name="q2" value="8GB">
            <img width="50px" height="50px" 
src="http://wepriceit.webs.com/Images/8GB.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="tablebuttons" type="radio" name="q2" value="16GB">
            <img width="50px" height="50px" 
src="http://wepriceit.webs.com/Images/16GB.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br class="clear" />
<div class="question">
    <h4>What color is your phone?</h4>
        <div class="radio" id="form">
            <div class="tablebuttons" type="radio" name="q3" value="iPhone-3GS">
                <img width="50px" height="50px" 
src="http://wepriceit.webs.com/Images/iPhone-3GS.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="tablebuttons" type="radio" name="q3" value="iPhone-4">
                <img width="50px" height="50px" 
src="http://wepriceit.webs.com/Images/iPhone-4.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="tablebuttons" type="radio" name="q3" value="iPhone-4S">
                <img width="50px" height="50px" 
src="http://wepriceit.webs.com/Images/iPhone-4S.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="tablebuttons" type="radio" name="q3" value="iPhone-5">
                <img width="50px" height="50px" 
src="http://wepriceit.webs.com/Images/iPhone-5.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<br class="clear" />
<div id="linkDiv">
    <input id="next_button" type="button" disabled="disabled" value="Next" />
</div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MXYZT/

Comment: your fiddle doesnt work out

Comment: Please try to reduce this to the smallest size possible that still shows the problem.  It's quite a mess.

Comment: what is  `<div class="tablebuttons" type="radio"`

Comment: "tablebuttons" keeps my css images specifically in that code and "type="radio"" tells the images that they are radio buttons and to act as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated your fiddle with working code:

http://jsfiddle.net/nwxLM/

```
$("html,body").animate({scrollTop :questions.eq(i).offset().top})
```

Here is the full function:

```
var showQuestions = function (index) {
    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        if (i < index) {
            questions.eq(i).css("display", "block");

        } else {
            questions.eq(i).css("display", "none");
        }
    }

    if (index > 1) {
        // only scroll to the questions after the first one is clicked
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop : $(questions.eq(index - 1)).offset().top
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want it to automatically scroll on page load, only when a button is clicked.

Comment: check out the fiddle I posted in the answer - i have it scrolling when button is clicked

Comment: When I visit the webpage with the code on my website it automatically scrolls to question 1. I'll try again.

Comment: Ah, i see. you are calling addQuestion(1) on page load. I'll update the code to prevent that

Comment: Perfect but I have one other question about this. When you click on question 3 or anything past that, why does it jump back to every question before that? Is it possible to make it just go straight to the next question instead?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36509/discussion-between-user2680614-and-jonathan-crowe)

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: questions.eq(i).offset().top}, 'slow');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MXYZT/2/

Comment: I don't want it to automatically scroll on page load, only when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the current question (let's say `.active`).  Then build a scrollToActive function and run it after every answer event.

Here's an example:

```
function scrollToActive() {
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('.active').offset().top},10);
}
```

On every answer event, you'll want to `removeClass('active')` and add it to the next.